# populate textbox from dropdown list value - asp.net with vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to get an "onchange" (not sure still new to asp) event to enter the select value text into a text box . I can seem to call the function.

here is my code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ownerdpdnlst" runat="server" ontextChanged="execvalchanged" >
                     <asp:ListItem Value="(Choose One)">Choose one...</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="name1">name1</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="name2">name2</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="name3">name3</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="name4">name4</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Value="name5">name5</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</asp:TableCell>
```

here is my vb.net code

```
<script runat=server>
    Public Sub execvalchanged(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ownerdpdnlst.SelectedIndexChanged
        executortxtbx.Text = ownerdpdnlst.SelectedValue
        MsgBox(ownerdpdnlst.SelectedValue)
    End Sub
</SCRIPT>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Did you add the event handler explicitly or is that a designer generated one?

Comment: In `aspx` You define `OnTextChanged` but in code behind `SelectedIndexChanged`. In `aspx`, Instead `ontextChanged="execvalchanged"` use `OnSelectedIndexChanged="execvalchanged"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In aspx You define OnTextChanged but in code behind SelectedIndexChanged. In aspx, Instead ontextChanged="execvalchanged" use OnSelectedIndexChanged="execvalchanged"–  nelekSep 12 at 6:32